# How to create wi-fi packet sniffer?

Tags: java, android, wifi, sniffer

I have long been studying the topics of how to create an WI-FI sniffer for android.

I work on the network routing algorithm, and my first goal is to listen to all network traffic. The second task - is to send broadcast messages. This is possible with on android phones? Yes, I got root access. Where can I read about what I want to do? This is done through sockets?

I do not want to adhere some protocols (eg WI-FI direct) and work with the existing ip-address system. I need the lowest level of interaction of OSI.

Comment: First thing that is required for WiFi sniffer is that driver should support so called *monitor* mode. Please note, this mode quite often is not supported on desktop systems, so don't expect this to be supported on your Android device. Even more, I worked for 5 years as a senior software WiFi engineer for one of the major Android vendors out there, and if I remember correctly we released only **one** device that had support for monitor mode, and it was based on BCM4330.

Comment: Second, Android does not have support for monitor mode, so it will be pain in the ass to extend Android API with this support. Of course, if you don't want to touch Android framework at all, and want to utilise standard Linux tools - you're on the safe side.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is impossible to establish a connection without sockets. One of the devices have to be a server, and another client

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that for professionals it is a very stupid question, but: how sniffers work? Sniffers did not make a connection? Or am I wrong?

Comment: What you do not like in the existing protocols and technology with sockets?

Comment: I want to explore how to work what I'm trying to do. Advise me good articles or books about my subject.

Comment: This will help you to simulate the algorithm

Comment: ;D Thanks, but I already did that. Now the real tests are needed.

Comment: I mean NS3 simulator